# React JS & Recoil set/get on select/selectFamily for specific attribute

Tags: reactjs, json, recoiljs

I use Recoil state management in ReactJS to preserve a keyboard letters data, for example

```
lettersAtom = atom(
  key: 'Letters'
  default: {
     allowed : ['A','C','D']
     pressedCounter : {'A':2, 'D':5}
  }
)

lettersPressedSelect = selector({
        key: 'LettersPressed',
        get: ({ get }) => get(lettersAtom).pressedCounter, //Not work, returns undefined
        set: () => ({ set }, pressedLetter) => {
            let newState = {...lettersAtom};
            newState.pressedCounter[pressedLetter]++;
            set(lettersAtom, newState);
        }
}),
```

In functional component i use

```
const [letters,setLetters] = useRecoilState(lettersAtom);
const [pressedCounter, setPressedCounter] = useRecoilState(lettersPressedSelect);
```

each time the a keyboard letter pressed the pressedCounter I want to increased for corresponded letter like that

```
setPressedCounter('A');
setPressedCounter('C'); ///etc...
```

How to achieve that ? Does recoil have a way to get/set a specific part/sub of json attribute ? (without make another atom? - I want to keep "Single source of truth")
Or do you have a suggetion  better best practice  to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code: no `const`, braces in `atom` call and no `get` inside the `set`. You also need spread the `pressedCounter`.

Overwise your solution works fine.

In Recoil you update the whole atom. So in this particular case you probably don't need the selector. Here is a working example with both approaches:

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-wind-kosp7o?file=/src/App.js

It a best-practice to keep atom values rather simple.

Comment: The problem was the let newState = {...lettersAtom};  sould be let newState = {...get(lettersAtom)};  because returned type of RecoilState rather than the real json. all the other things no matter . Also Thank you for the example in codesandbox :)

Comment: also in https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/selector/ not describe enough the use of get in the "set" body method. We can use the set(stage, newStageValues) but without spread and merge two stages. But we have to remember set in recoil is like setStage in react, we can use prevStage closure

Answer (score 2):

You can update the state based on the existing state in a selector in a couple ways.  You could use the `get()` callback from the setter or you could use the updater form of the setter where you pass a function as the new value which receives the current value as a parameter.

However, it's a good practice to have symmetry for the getter and setters of a selector.  For example, here's a selector family which gets and sets the value of a counter:

```
const lettersPressedState = selectorFamily({
    key: 'LettersPressed',
    get: letter => ({ get }) => get(lettersAtom).pressedCounter[letter],
    set: letter => ({ set }, newPressedValue) => {
        set(lettersAtom, existingLetters => ({
            ...existingLetters,
            pressedCounter: {
                ...existingLetters.pressedCounter,
                [letter]: newPressedValue,
            },
        });
    },
});
```

But note that the above will set the new value with a new counter value where you originally wanted the setter to increment the value.  That's not really setting a new value and is more like an action.  For that you don't really need a selector abstraction at all and can just use an updater when setting the atom:

```
  const [letters, setLetters] = useRecoilState(lettersAtom);
  const incrementCounter = pressedLetter =>
      setLetters(existingLetters => ({
          ...existingLetters,
          pressedCounter: {
              ...existingLetters.pressedCounter,
              [pressedLetter]: (existingLetters.pressedCounter[pressedLetter] ?? 0) + 1,
          },
      });
```

Note that this uses the updater form of the selector to ensure it is incrementing based on the current value and not a potentially stale value as of the rendering.

Or, you can potentially simplify things more and use simpler values in the atoms by using an atom family for the pressed counter:

```
const pressedState = atomFamily({
    key: 'LettersPressed',
    default: 0,
});
```

And you can update in your component like the following:

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useRecoilState(pressedState(letter));
  const incrementCounter = setCounter(x => x + 1);
```

Or create an general incrementor callback:

```
  const incrementCounter = useRecoilCallback(({ set }) => pressedLetter => {
      set(pressedState(pressedLetter)), x => x + 1 );
  });
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/discussions/1953

Answer (score -1):

So the sort answer help by user4980215 is:

```
set: () => ({ get, set }, pressedLetter) => {
            let newState = {...get(lettersAtom)};
            newState.pressedCounter[pressedLetter]++;
            set(lettersAtom, newState);
        }
```

Comment: While the spread would create a new object for the state, it is only a shallow copy.  It would still be referencing the same arrays and thus incorrectly mutate the state objects.